# Editors not honoring Python shell aliases

Tags: python, homebrew, zsh, atom-editor

I run macOS Catalina with zshell.

Out of the box the os has one python2 and one python3 version in `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python3`. I have installed a newer python3 via Homebrew. That version is in `/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3`.

I have added aliases to my `~/.zshrc`-file so that both `python` and `python3` will launch into the 3.8 Homebrew version.

When using editors (e.g. Atom) that run python scripts by calling `python3` this aliasing does not seem to work. I guess this is because it is specific to the terminal shell.

What is a better way of getting my homebrew python3.8 to become the default python on my system?

Comment: probably the Atom's shell doesnt use zsh.... so adjust simply your ~/.bashrc

Comment: @koalaok Tried that, but didn't work

Comment: Since Atom does not run Pythons scripts out of the box, it would be helpful to know which third-party package you're using to so. If it's the `script` package, make sure to read the [dedicated chapter on Python](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script#atom-cant-find-node--ruby--python--my-socks) in its README!

Comment: Regarding your aliases, shouldn't you use the `brew link` command instead?

Comment: @idleberg `brew link`, IIUC, just links `/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3` to `/usr/local/bin/python3`; it wouldn't be useful for creating a new link `/usr/local/bin/python` to `/.../python3`.

Comment: A good title communicates the essence of your problem so a reader looking at a search results listing can tell if its answers are likely to be helpful to them before they click through and read the body. I've tried to edit towards that end.

Comment: @DIGSUM : Likely the shell launched from your editor does not source any of the files where you defined the aliases. This could be the case if the editor uses `sh` as a shell, or if it runs a non-interactive, non-login shell. Note that at least in bash, aliases are by default disabled inside scripts anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Don't uses aliases for selecting alternate programs. Use your `PATH` variable to manage your preferences.

Start by creating a local `bin` directory if you don't already have one.

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
```

Assuming your `PATH` is already set up to prefer Homebrew versions over system-installed versions, add `~/bin` to the front of the path.

```
# In .bash_profile
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

Now, create a symbolic link `~/bin/python` to the desired Python 3 interpreter.

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3 ~/bin/python
```

Now when you run `python`, you'll get your Homebrew `python3.8` interpreter. You can still access the system Python 2 with `/usr/bin/python` when needed. Your editors should also inherit and respect your `PATH` variable, unless it is configured to use a specific hard-coded path.

Note that Homebrew still(?) links `/usr/local/bin/python` to its own Python 2 interpreter; I don't recommend changing that to `python3`, lest other Homebrew-managed programs get Python 3 when they require Python 2, hence the use of `~/bin`. (There's still a chance that programs using `python` via path lookup will assume it is Python 2, but this should minimize the problems.)